# Экземпляры класса как переменные метода другого класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Пример конечно совершенно абстрактный, но, например, у меня есть 2 класса, в которых содержатся атрибуты, над которыми мне нужно совершить какие-то действия. В классе С я вызываю в методе экземпляры класса как параметры метода и таким образом я вызывают нужные атрибуты

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x, x1):
        self.x = x
        self.x1 = x1

class B():
    def __init__(self, y, y1):
        self.y = y
        self.y1 = y1

class C():
    def __init__(self, ex_a, ex_b):
        self.ex_a = ex_a
        self.ex_b = ex_b
        self.d = self.dist()

    def dist(self):
        return self.ex_a.x + self.ex_b.y
```

Можно ли так оформлять метод `C.dist()`? Или нужно наследовать классы A и B, и как осуществить это наследование в этом случае?

P.S. Без статических методов и функций, потому что может в дальнейшем потребуется использовать атрибут `A.x1`

P.S.S Ошибка ли определять атрибуты класса так или нужно как в C++ определять атрибут как `self.__X`? Я так и не разобрался с приватностью в python

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. Как я понял, вы хотите выводить сумму функцией dist, и получается, например:

smth = c(1,3)
print(smth.dist())

Но проблема кроется уже в  self.ex_a.x и self.ex_b.у, а именно: когда вы вызываете self.ex_a, то это self.ex_a уже является числом, которое мы указали в скобках (т.е. 1) и получается так, что вы пытаетесь у класса int вызвать атрибут 'x', которого отродясь не было

Comment: Чтобы реализовать похожее поведение используйте дескрипторы.

Comment: @DiHASTRO self.ex_a - это экземпляр класса A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример **слишком** абстрактный, чтобы сказать что-то конкретное. Выглядит примерно как:

> У меня есть какая-то вещь, которую мне нужно отремонтировать. Можно ли использовать отвертку? Или нужно использовать молоток? Если молоток, то как правильно его использовать?

Вы просите подсказать, **как** что-то сделать, не говоря о том, **что именно** пытаетесь сделать.

---

Наследование - не панацея, это своего рода инструмент. Его нужно использовать тогда, когда этого требует предметная область.

Например, класс А будет кошкой, класс B - собакой, класс C - корзиной (внутри которой и кошка, и собака), для которой нужно вычислить общий вес. И наследовать корзину от кошки и собаки для вычисления их общего веса методом класса корзины **крайне неверно**. Да и вообще, множественного наследования лучше избегать, т.к. с ним связаны определенные проблемы.

> Можно ли так оформлять метод C.dist()?

Вполне, а почему нет? Единственное, было бы неплохо сделать через свойства класса.

> Ошибка ли определять атрибуты класса так, или нужно как в C++ определять атрибут как `self.__X`? Я так и не разобрался с приватностью в python.

По поводу приватности есть [хорошее объяснение](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python). Там же есть и про свойства.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы наследовать класс, просто запишите его в скобках, например:

input:

```
class A:
    def func1(self):
        print('Первая функция')

class B:
    def func2(self):
        print('Вторая функция')

class C(A, B): #наследование классов A и B
    def func3(self):
        print('Третья функция')

c = C()

c.func1()
c.func2()
c.func3()
```

output:

```
Первая функция
Вторая функция
Третья функция
```

Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: совсем нет, мне интересно нужно ли наследовать или нет, а если нужно, то как это организовать, потому что на интуитивном уровне получение атрибута класса C как условную сумму атрибутов атрибутов является слишком нагруженным и есть ощущение, что можно наследовать классы  A и B и получить результат dist() как сумма атрибутов класса C в чистом виде